# Rolling mean function similar to pandas in zoo

Tags: r, ggplot2, zoo

I want to create a rolling mean of some geochemical data. Currently, I have data for every 1 mm from 0mm to 45.7 mm and I want to average every 10 mm to create 1 cm averages.

This is the data at the moment but it still is not giving me 1 cm averages. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong? Thanks

```
wapPbTa<-read.csv("wappbta.csv",header=TRUE)

wapPbTa<-wapPbTa[-c(251:458), ] 

library(ggplot2)
library(tidypaleo)
library(zoo)
width <- 10

RM<-rollmean(x = wapPbTa$PbTa, k = width,fill=NA)

##Averaged data

ggplot(wapPbTa, aes(x =RM , y = Depth))+
  labs(y = "Depth (cm)")+
  geom_lineh(size=1)+
  geom_point(size=2)+
  theme_classic()+
  scale_y_reverse()

## Unaveraged data
ggplot(wapPbTa, aes(x =PbTa , y = Depth))+
  labs(y = "Depth (cm)")+
  geom_lineh(size=1)+
  geom_point(size=2)+
  theme_classic()+
  scale_y_reverse()

structure(list(Depth = c(0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 
0.8, 0.9, 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9), PbTa = c(0.163857678, 
0.161569533, 0.086305592, 0, 0.006086142, 0, 0, 0.044096031, 
0.050739958, 0.088385995, 0.104100946, 0.133012821, 0, 0.127524872, 
0.046368715, 0.02514558, 0.109383676, 0.081979695, 0.0766503, 
0.064679583)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: The data you posted only has 6 rows, it's better if you post the output of `dput(head(wapPbTa, 20))`. (This `wapPbTa` is the data set after subsetting).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't know you could do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of problems generally has to do with reshaping the data. The format should be the long format and the data is in wide format. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) on how to reshape the data from wide to long format.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tidypaleo)
library(zoo)

width <- 10
wapPbTa$RM <- rollmeanr(x = wapPbTa$PbTa, k = width, fill = NA)

wapPbTa %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Depth) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y = Depth, colour = name)) +
  geom_lineh(size = 1) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  scale_y_reverse() +
  scale_colour_manual(
    breaks = c("PbTa", "RM"),
    values = c("black", "blue")
  ) +
  labs(y = "Depth (cm)") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't realised it was to do with the data not being pivoted but that makes sense.

Comment: @SophieWilliams Note also that `ggplot` needs the vectors in `aes()` to be part of the data.frame, I have assigned `RM` as a new column.